# MySQL Function only once with group by

Tags: mysql, function, group-by

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT user_id, myMysqlFunction(user_id) FROM users_to_days GROUP BY user_id;
```

The table stores one row per user and day.
The problem is that MySql calls the Function `"myMysqlFunction(user_id)"` for every row and groups the rows after that. 
My target is to execute the Function just once (for performance reasons).

I tried the following state without success:

```
SELECT user_id, IF(`date` = min(`date`),myMysqlFunction(user_id),0) FROM users_to_days GROUP BY user_id;
```

MySql still executes the statement for every row.
If I write a static date (for example '2014-09-01') - it works:

```
SELECT user_id, IF(`date` = '2014-09-01',myMysqlFunction(user_id),0) FROM users_to_days GROUP BY user_id;
```

But I don't know the min. date for the user at the time of execution. (its not the same for every user)

Comment: *"The problem is that MySql calls the Function "myMysqlFunction(user_id)" for every row and groups the rows after that"* How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @ypercube: I executed "insert into tmp(user_id, date, execute_time) values (param_user_id, param_date, now());" inside of the function and got one line for every user_id and every date.

Comment: Add the code of the function in your question. From what you say, I can't figure out what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try a subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, myMysqlFunction(user_id) 
FROM (SELECT user_id 
      FROM users_to_days 
      GROUP BY user_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: comment got split up, I wanted to say:

I meant: try $date = date('Y-m-d');, that will get the time the user runs it. Put that in min($date), and it should be working.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Mm, my comment got split up. I meant: try $date = date('Y-m-d');, that will get the time the user runs it. Put that in min($date), and it should be working.